# How do I make a UIBarButtonItem 'glow'?

Tags: iphone, uikit, uibarbuttonitem, uibarbuttonitemstyle

In the Maps app, when you press the tracking button in the lower left hand corner, it glows showing that it's pressed.  This makes it behave like a radio button, and it will un-glow once you move the map.  Is there a simple way to but a button into the pressed state?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Set its style to UIBarButtonItemStyleDone.

Comment: UIBarButtonItemStyleDone is a "blue" button.  I don't think this is a glow, right?

Comment: Well it's not technically a glow, but it is what the Maps app does (as mentioned in the question).

Comment: This achieves the blue, but not the glow.

Answer (score 11):

I believe you are looking for the showsTouchWhenHighlighted property for the UIButton class.  Give this a try.

```
myButton.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = YES;
```

Comment: The question is about a UIBarButtonItem not a UIButton, so this is not relevant.

Comment: It's not clear from the question detail that that is the case.  And anyways, you can create a UIBarButtonItem with a UIButton,  so I believe my answer is relevant.  UIBarButtonItem *buttonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:myButton];

Comment: I was searching for effect for UIButton, so thanks for your response!

Answer (score 3):

You could make  its customview  a custom button like this:

`

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"someimage"];
UIImage *imageHL = [UIImage imageNamed:@"someimage_selected"];
button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

[button setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setImage:imageHL forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(doStuff:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];    
myBarButtonItem.customView = button;
```

`

Answer (score 1):

Use `UIBarButtonItemStylePlain`.

> UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
>   Glows when tapped.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a UIBarButtonItem with `image/text` or `UIBarButtonSystemItem`, then use `UIBarButtonItemStylePlain`

```
barButton.style = UIBarButtonItemStylePlain;
```

If you have a UIBarButtonItem with a custom view, then, for each `UIButton` should add the following code:

```
uiButton.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = YES;
```